# I want to create a nested array consisting of all elements from another array but grouped into two

Tags: c++

I want to create a nested array (v2) consisting of all elements from another array (arr) but grouped into two.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > v2;
int arr[8] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
//I want the v2 to be: {{0,1}, {2,3}, {4,5}, {6,7}}
std::cout << "v2.size = "<< v2.size() << '\n';
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++){
    //I want the v2 to be: {{0,1}, {2,3}, {4,5}, {6,7}}
        v2[i][j] = arr[2*i];
        v2[i][j+1] = arr[2*i+1];
    }
}
//No output...
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        std::cout<<v2[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't just assign to elements of an empty vector, you need to resize it first

Comment: It would probably be better if you compute the number of pairs based on the number of elements in `arr`  (rather than hard-coding `4`).   And, in doing that, deal with the possibility that `arr` may have an odd number of elements.    Doing that doesn't take much more effort, but will be easier to maintain if (say) you need to modify the data so it has 15 pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reserve space in the vector before assigning to it using `operator[]`

Change

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v2;
```

to

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v2(4, std::vector<int>(2));
```

Comment: @lenik It's been compilable since C++11.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I now have my desired v2. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > v2;
  int arr[8] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
  //I want the v2 to be: {{0,1}, {2,3}, {4,5}, {6,7}}
  std::cout << "v2.size = "<< v2.size() << '\n';
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        v2.push_back( std::pair<int, int>( arr[2*i], arr[2*i+1]) );
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        std::cout << v2[i].first << v2[i].second << std::endl;
  }
```

Comment: Great idea, using `pair` to keep all of the data contiguous. `std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> v2` will give them the same benefits and still allow `v2[i][j]` access.

Comment: I see, using pair is a great solution. Thank you for your answer.